# Failed to copy error while copying mobileprovision file in Jenkins

Tags: macos, jenkins, jenkins-build-flow, mobileprovision

jenkins is installed in OS X Sierra and I am trying to create a job
I have uploaded provisioning file in KeyChain and Provisioning Profiles Management plugin.
In job configuration, in Build environment section, Mobile Provisioning Profile, corresponding profile is selected.
When build is run, I get these errors

```
FATAL: Failed to copy /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/kpp_upload/abcdfe-e441-407b-ba4a-34e97bf71f5b.mobileprovision to /Users/*****/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/abcdfe-e441-407b-ba4a-34e97bf71f5b.mobileprovision
         java.io.IOException: Failed to copy /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/kpp_upload/abcdfe-e441-407b-ba4a-34e97bf71f5b.mobileprovision to /Users/*****/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/abcdfe-e441-407b-ba4a-34e97bf71f5b.mobileprovision
    at .     
        hudson.FilePath.copyTo(FilePath.java:2018)
    at .                  com.sic.plugins.kpp.KPPProvisioningProfilesBuildWrapper.copyProvisioningProfiles(KPPProvisioningProfilesBuildWrapper.java:161)
    at .             com.sic.plugins.kpp.KPPProvisioningProfilesBuildWrapper.setUp(KPPProvisioningProfilesBuildWrapper.java:99)
    at .   hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:156)
    at .              hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at     hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at     hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at     hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at     hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
    Caused by:     java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/*****/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/abcdfe-e441-407b-ba4a-34e97bf71f5b.mobileprovision (Permission denied)
    at     java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at     java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at     java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at     java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at     hudson.FilePath.write(FilePath.java:1907)
    at     hudson.FilePath.copyTo(FilePath.java:2011)
    ... 8 more
    Finished: FAILURE
```

When I run a command in terminal to copy file from source folder to destination folder, it succeeds. But jenkins is unable to copy

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the target path has a folder "Provisioning Profiles" with a space in it.

Either place it into a folder with no white space, or escape the white space in your code.

```
<string path>.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met the similar problem because of the access permission denied.I think that you installed the Jenkins by `.pkg` file,because your Jenkins directory is in `/Users/Shared/Jenkins`.

**This kind of installation of Jenkins on macOS is really easy to cause the file access permission error.**

The above error is not very easy to solve,I have not solve the problem yet directly.

> I have reinstalled the Jenkins by `brew` command,and I have no permission error,because the Jenkins installation directory is not in `Shared`,but in the `User` directory.

If you don't have Homebrew installed,use the command to install Homebrew in your terminal.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Use the command to install Jenkins.

```
brew install jenkins-lts
```